# JavaScript displaying code instead of running

Tags: javascript

For some reason my JavaScript is now displaying as code instead of running. It happened after I started optimizing my JavaScript and CSS and minifying it. 
Anyone care to help me :/

http://PattersonCode.ca

Comment: Anyone care to explain the down vote?

Comment: Not mine, Austen, but I did vote to close. The reason I selected: *Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. See SSCCE.org for guidance.* Basically, include the relevant portions of your page code here, and describe what you changed. Good link in the close reason, by the way - absolutely worth a read.

Comment: Well, the problem page is linked. You can see the full source and how it renders.

Comment: ...and then the problem's fixed, and this question's worthless, @Thilo.

Comment: I agree, narrowing it down to only what's relevant increases the probability of someone spending time figuring it out

Comment: But I linked the page, and the source displays fine. It's just the JS messing up..

Comment: In general a question on StackOverflow is meant to be self contained, part of the reason for that is because the question is also meant for future visitors. That said the problem seems to be this *link element* `<link data-skrollr-stylesheet="" href="http://pattersoncode.ca/incls/css/style.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" class="css-finalize-read">`, try removing that.

Comment: The linked page has 18 separate script elements and the equivalent of several thousand lines of minified code. If you want help to debug it, reduce your problem to the minimum required to reproduce it. If it's too big to post here, keep reducing. Annoying users by telling them that their browser is out of date isn't a good start.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: Check out the answer by gp. That seems to be a useful thing to know for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css "incls/css/style.min.css" sets display to inline-block for all elements.

check the line:

```
*{display:inline-block}
```

by default script tag is set to display:none. but your css sets script also to inline-block;

add `script{display:none;}` to your css and your page will render fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to change a bit gp's answer.

You need to add 2 css rules in your css file which is located here:  http://pattersoncode.ca/incls/css/style.min.css

```
head{display:none;}
```

and

```
script{display:none;}
```

Using just the script rule will not work as you will still have the css rules displaying in your page.

This 2 rules will do the work for you. Cheers

Comment: you are right. I thought that hint is enough to get Austen solve his problem :)